# BLURRY TEXT - WINDOW FORMS - PANEL - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.7.2

I know this topic has MANY questions/answers but I am still drawing blanks. Running Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019. I have created a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework). Target is .NET Framework 4.7.2. I have a Form created with a Panel on the form. The Panel is sized to 384x576 which is approximate 4" x 6". That is the exact size I have my page size set to. When I print preview (via code) it looks clear, but when it prints to my laser printer, some of the text is blurred. The text is a Label.
My apologies up front, almost 80% of the code has been pieced together from "MANY" websites, so if you see any specific part of my code that looks like your code, sorry I am not giving proper credits in the footnotes.

Here is some of my code:

PRINT BUTTON

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myprintdialog As New PrintDialog
    memoryimage = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
    Panel1.DrawToBitmap(memoryimage, Panel1.ClientRectangle)

    If myprintdialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim value As System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
        value = myprintdialog.PrinterSettings
        myprintdialog.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintDocument1.PrintController = New StandardPrintController()
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.White
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles 
     PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryimage, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

and even app.manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
<application>
</application>
</compatibility>
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
  <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
</windowsSettings>
</application>
```

This can't be that difficult, or is it? I hope someone sees something that I am doing wrong. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias`

Comment: Looking at this again, you may need to set the `Graphics.TextRenderingHint` property. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint?view=net-5.0

Comment: I tried those two specifically and from what I can ascertain, they didn't change what I already have,. Those commands have several options under each. Tomorrow I'll try to go back through them and look at the different options. Michael, thanks for your prompt help so far.

Comment: I'm sorry this got down-voted. It seems like a good question to me and is clear. +1 from me.

Comment: Anytime you print an image of text it's not going to be nearly as clear as printing the actual text. Most printers have a dpi range from 300 to 1200, higher for professional printers. Your screen monitor is 96 dpi, so it's going to have to scale up and hence it is blurry.